# Specify Domain Server For HttpClient Kerberos in .NET

Tags: kerberos, dotnet-httpclient, spnego

I can successfully call a SPNEGO web service on WebLogic/Java (on subforest1.forest1.company.com) from a C# application using HttpClient running on the same subforest. It reverts to NTLM if I run from a different subforest and forest (subforest2.forest2.company.com).

Can I tell HttpClient to use a specific domain controller on a different subforest (machine1.subforest1.forest1.company.com)?

Also, I figured out how to specify a SPN using System.Net.AuthenticationManager.CustomTargetNameDictionary.Add(uri.AbsoluteUri, spn) but I haven't figured out how to find the default SPN.